# Prevent same call on an api response

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I'm learning to use calls on APIs and I'm trying to get my API response to not return the same data over and over again, currently, it does despite using setInterval, I have tried changing the order and making it async but am currently not able to figure out how to change this.

The idea is to make an original call to the API on page load, then after 6 or so seconds, make the call again but change the response automatically hence the setInterval.

Here is my code:

```
const advice = document.getElementById("advice");
const adviceNum = document.getElementById("adviceNum");

const slip_id = Math.random() * 100;
console.log(slip_id)

fetch(`https://api.adviceslip.com/advice/${slip_id}`)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }) 
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        const returnedAdvice = data.slip.advice;
        console.log(returnedAdvice);
        const idAdvice = data.slip.id;
    
        adviceNum.innerText = `ADVICE #${idAdvice}`;
        advice.innerText = `"${returnedAdvice}"`;

        setInterval(() => {
            console.log(data);
            const returnedAdvice = data.slip.advice;
            console.log(returnedAdvice);
            const idAdvice = data.slip.id;
    
            adviceNum.innerText = `ADVICE #${idAdvice}`;
            advice.innerText = `"${returnedAdvice}"`;
        }, 8000)
    })
```

Would appreciate any help on what I'm doing wrong here!

Comment: Why would exactly the same request result in a different response?

Comment: You cannot set Interval becuase once you invoke the api function then it returns the data and the whole process is finished. Yes, there's some interval going on in the background but when you make another request then the same function will be invoked again. It will not be the same interval. Everything will start all over again. You can pick a random number or check the local time if you want .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're making a fetch request and when the data returns from that single request; you console.log etc.

Instead try the following, wrap your fetch request in the setInterval

```js
  setInterval(async function(){
    const data = await fetch(`https://api.adviceslip.com/advice/${slip_id}`);
    // check your response 
    // compute your values 
    // add them to the dom
  }, 8000);
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited it to this and thanks to your suggestion, we have success!
setInterval(async function(){
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.adviceslip.com/advice?t=` + Math.random(), {cache: 'no-cache'});
    if(response.ok) {
// do stuff
    }
  }, 8000);